# My oracle local database becomes full and locked

Tags: oracle, batch-file, truncate, audit-tables

I have been using the truncate audit table to solve the issue.

Is there any other better solution than using truncate and clear Aud$ table every day ?

If I use batch file and set task scheduler for clear the audit table every 12 hours  does it works ?

Kindly , I need an assist in this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT` to enable automatic periodic cleanup of your audit trail.  You do not need to invent your own process for this.

Refer to the *Oracle Database PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference* documentation.

Comment: Could you please provide me the syntax ???